# How to hide entire row based on value in a table column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through each cell in column 2 of table `Test1` and if the value is 0, hide the entire row.

When I run the following code, I get error `Method 'Range' of object' _Global' Failed`.  The debugger highlights `Range(cell.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True`

```
    Dim cell As Range
    ' loop through each cell in column 2 of Test1
    For Each cell In Range("Test1[2]")
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            ' Hide each row that contains 0.
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next cell
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Range(cell.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True` ---> `cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True`.